# Custom post types with custom directories

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, directory

I'd like to run a WordPress install with open registration so that anyone can sign up and post to a custom post type that would live at... domain.com/open/date/the-post-title

I'd also like to run a blog on the same WP install that only I can post to that would live at... domain.com/blog/date/the-post-title

Is something like this possible without running MultiSite (which I believe would force the blog to live at blog.domain.com)?

Thanks.

Eddie

Answer (score 1):

> Is something like this possible without running MultiSite (which I believe would force the blog to live at blog.domain.com)?

Not quite. There are two basic modes multisite installation can operate in:

- sub-domains ( *site.domain.com* )
- sub-directories ( *domain.com/site* )

As far as I remember in subdirectory installation main blog is also forced to have `/blog/` at start of permalinks for compatbility.

So for your requirements sub-directory install with main blog at *domain.com* (posts at *domain.com/blog/*) and additional blog at *domain.com/open/* seems to fit.

Comment: Didn't know that MultiSite had a subdirectory option. Thanks Rarst.